# How to get info from three tables with a MIN (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, min

I have four tables, like these:

```
items
| id | name  | category |
-------------------------
| 1  | item1 | toy      |  
| 2  | item2 | toy      |
| 3  | item3 | home     |
-------------------------
items2
| id | name  | category | size |
--------------------------------
| 1  | itemA | toy      | s    |
| 2  | itemB | home     | l    |
--------------------------------
prices
| items.id | price |
--------------------
|  1       |  10   |
|  1       |  15   |
|  2       |  20   |
|  3       |  25   |
|  3       |  20   |
--------------------
prices
| items2.id | price |
--------------------
|  1        |  15   |
|  2        |  50   |
|  2        |  40   |
--------------------
```

I need to get a result which have both, items and items2, with the MIN of each price. In this example the result should be something like this:

```
| id | name  | category | size | minprice |
-------------------------------------------
| 1  | item1 | toy      | null | 10       |
| 2  | item2 | toy      | null | 20       |
| 3  | item3 | home     | null | 20       |
| 1  | itemA | toy      | s    | 15       |
| 2  | itemB | home     | l    | 40       |
-------------------------------------------
```

I also should be able to `ORDER BY minprice`, but I'm sure when I know how to join them I can do that too.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest that you merge the tables items and items2. If a field doesn't apply to an item (such as size in this case), that is what null is for.

I haven't tested that this works but you want something like:

```
SELECT i.id, name, category, null as size, min(prices.price) from items i
JOIN prices on prices.id = i.id
GROUP BY i.id, i.name, i.category, size
UNION ALL
SELECT i2.id, name, category, size, min(prices2.price) from items2 i2
JOIN prices2 on prices2.id = i2.id
GROUP BY i2.id, i2.name, i2.category, i2.size
```

Comment: IMHO `UNION ALL` would be better since there is no need to eliminate duplicates.

Comment: You can't select non-aggregates which you didn't include in the group by. MySQL allows such a query but it's unreliable and won't work on any sane db.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, you are over complicating things. You only need one table. For tuples in the item relation where there is no size, simply mark it as null.

This is probably an oversimplification. If prices are "sales" or something similar, you could use a left join to build the relation you are looking for

so

SELECT i.id, i.name, i.category, i.size, p.price as min_price FROM items i LEFT JOIN price p where p.price <= 40 ORDER BY min_price